# How to replace image on hover on menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website I have a menu bar with image. I want to replace the image whenever an user hover on that menu item. This is my menu:

```
 <ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
    <li class="topfirst"><a class="pressed" href="#" style="width:98px;"><img src="images/home.png" alt=""/>Home</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:98px;">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:98px;"><img src="images/home.png" alt=""/>Work</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:98px;">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:98px;"><img src="images/home.png" alt=""/>Team</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:98px;">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:98px;"><img src="images/home.png" alt=""/>Blog</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:98px;">&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#" style="width:98px;"><img src="images/home.png" alt=""/>Reach Us</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Now I want to replace of that image of that menu on which user has hoverd. For this purpose I am using jQuery. I did this but I could not proceed.

```
$('#css3menu1').find('li').hover(function()
                    {

                    }
                );
```

or is there any other way, so that I can replace images?

Comment: All items will have same image as in this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your each of the `li` elements has an `img` element in it.

```
(function () {
    /*Wrap inside anonymous function to prevent conflicts with global variables*/
    var orgSrc, // original source of image
        $element; // the image

    $("#css3menu1").find("li").hover(function () {
        $element = $(this).find("img");
        orgSrc = $element.prop("src");
        $element.prop("src", "http://placehold.it/200x200");
    }, function () {
        $element.prop("src", orgSrc);
    });
})();
```

### [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/bmYa9/2/)

Comment: @ElGuapo Moral of the story: Always keep JSFiddle open in another tab while using Stackoverflow :D

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA Yeah...  :)

Comment: you are provide the image source after the hover out , i don't want to provide as i want when mouse out , it should contain the initial image

Comment: thanks alot sir, it's working fine. 
sir here actually i my new image name is "HomeH" and my old image name is Home . so i just want to append "H" in old image source. which will replace my old image with new image. for this i have created a new variable $newsrc, 


edited your code like this , but not working .
var  $orgsrc,$element,$newsrc;
    $("#css3menu1").find("li").hover(function () {
    $element = $(this).find("img");
    orgSrc = $element.prop("src");
     newsrc=orgSrc+'H';
    $element.prop("src", newsrc);
    }, function () {
    $element.prop("src", orgSrc);
   });

Comment: @AmitKumar Well you have declared `$orgSrc` but using it as `orgSrc`. Same for `newSrc`. I hope that clarified everything. Additionally, use `$` in front of variable names only for those variables which store a jQuery object (as in `$element`)

Comment: Love the anonymous function :)

Answer (score 2):

It is always recommended that you keep presentation and behavior away from `HTML`

Here the effect can be done with `CSS` `background-image` unless you are looking for some animation.

```
 <ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
    <li class="topfirst"><a id="home" class="pressed"href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="work">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="team">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="reachus">Reach Us</a></li>    
</ul>
```

---

```
#css3menu1 li{
    width:98px;
}

#css3menu1 li a{
    display:block; /* add the width and height you need */
}

#home{ background: transparent url(img/home.png) no-repeat left top; }
#home:hover{ background: transparent url(img/home-hover.png) no-repeat left top; }

#work{ background: transparent url(img/work.png) no-repeat left top; }
#work:hover{ background: transparent url(img/work-hover.png) no-repeat left top; }
```

---

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#css3menu1').find('li').hover(function()
                    {
                          $(this).first('img').attr('src', {hover over image source});
                    },
                    function()
                    {
                          $(this).first('img').attr('src', {hover out image source});
                    }
                );
```

Comment: ca you tell me , what is here "first" stand for ?
and on hover , i can provide, the image source, but when hover out, image should be as previous

Comment: "first" is the first instance of "img" under the "li" which you are hovering.

Answer (score 1):

Try

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LDGN5/)</kbd>

```
$('#css3menu1').find('li:has(img)').hover(function () { //attach hover if li has img
    var $this = $(this).find('img'); //cache selector
    $this.data('src',$this.prop('src'));//set old src to data 
    $this.prop('src', 'http://placehold.it/200x200'); // change img
}, function () {
    var $this = $(this).find('img'); //cache selector
    $this.prop('src', $this.data('src')); //get old image back
});
```

Comment: Great! But I was wondering how is the caching of `$this` going on when it is initialized two times?

Comment: @GaurangTandon both are different function and $this is local variable to these functions .

Comment: Ok, so it means that the data is being stored using jQuery `.data` method and retrieved later. P.S. I was something more of something like this --> http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/LDGN5/1/

Answer (score 1):

First your HTML code can be a little well written.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="css3menu1" class="topmenu">
    <li class="topfirst"><a class="pressed" href="#"><img src="images/home.png" alt=""/>Home</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#"><img src="images/home.png" alt=""/>Work</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#"><img src="images/home.png" alt=""/>Team</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#"><img src="images/home.png" alt=""/>Blog</a></li>
    <li class="topmenu"><a href="#"><img src="images/home.png" alt=""/>Reach Us</a></li>    
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    margin-right: 98px;
}
li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
li a {
    width:98px;
}
```

**JS**

@Gaurang Tandon's answer would be the best choice